# Regular expression matching alphanumeric only requiring both letters and numbers

Tags: java, regex

I want to match an alphanumeric string containing at least one letter and one number. Is there a simple way to combine the following into a single regular expression?

```
strValue.matches("[A-Z0-9]+")
    && strValue.matches(".*[A-Z].*")
    && strValue.matches(".*[0-9].*")
```

Comment: @m.buettner: Actually, that's wrong. `String.matches(String)` uses `Matcher.matches()` which matches against the entire string. The behaviour you describe is implemented in `Matcher.find()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use look ahead assertion.

```
strValue.matches("^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Z\\d]+$")
```

Comment: Why do you use a start of line?

Comment: To ensure that there are no non-alphanumerical characters before the start of the match (in fact, you should also add an anchor for the end of the string)

Comment: But the requirement was only that the string should contain a letter and a number. I don't see why you want to match the whole string.

Comment: @lilalinux The op said match a `alphanumeric` string.

Comment: @VincenzoSanchez Thanks, but `$` is needed for alphanumeric string